Changes in query duration for highly transactional table
I have recently noticed that one of the main queries that hits our busiest table fluctuates in terms of actual execution time by quite a lot and I'm struggling to understand why.
Below is the table:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [INST_NO] [binary](3) NOT NULL,
    [ACCT_NO] [binary](16) NOT NULL,
    [REC_NO] [binary](9) NOT NULL,
    [TRAN_DATE] [decimal](9, 0) NOT NULL,
    [POST_DATE] [decimal](9, 0) NULL,
    [POST_TIME] [decimal](9, 0) NULL,
    [JRNL_NO] [decimal](9, 0) NULL,
    [TRAN_TYPE] [decimal](2, 0) NULL,
    [DELI] [binary](1) NULL,
    [VAR_AREA] [binary](80) NULL,
    [UUID] [binary](36) NULL,
    [UUID_SEQ] [binary](2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [MyTablePK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [INST_NO] ASC,
    [ACCT_NO] ASC,
    [REC_NO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = AUTO)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_TRAN_DATE]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TRAN_DATE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__MyTable__POST_DATE__47EB5F47]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [POST_DATE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__MyTable__POST_TIME__48DF8380]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [POST_TIME]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__MyTable__JRNL_NO__49D3A7B9]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [JRNL_NO]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__MyTable__TRAN_TYPE__4AC7CBF2]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TRAN_TYPE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__MyTable__DELI__4BBBF02B]  DEFAULT (CONVERT([binary](1),replicate(char((0)),(1)))) FOR [DELI]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__MyTable__VAR_AREA__4CB01464]  DEFAULT (CONVERT([binary](80),replicate(char((0)),(80)))) FOR [VAR_AREA]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_UUID]  DEFAULT (CONVERT([binary](36),replicate(char((32)),(36)))) FOR [UUID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_UUID_SEQ]  DEFAULT (CONVERT([binary](2),replicate(char((48)),(2)))) FOR [UUID_SEQ]
GO

Query:
SELECT TOP 1  INST_NO ,ACCT_NO ,REC_NO ,TRAN_DATE ,POST_DATE ,POST_TIME ,JRNL_NO ,TRAN_TYPE ,DELI ,VAR_AREA ,ISNULL(UUID,CAST(REPLICATE(CHAR(32),36) as BINARY)) ,ISNULL(UUID_SEQ,CAST(REPLICATE(CHAR(48),2) as BINARY)) 
FROM MyTable                               
WHERE (INST_NO = @P1     AND  ACCT_NO = @P2     AND  REC_NO > @P3  )ORDER BY INST_NO  ASC, ACCT_NO  ASC, REC_NO  ASC

For some reason the query durations seem to fluctuate between an average of ~7ms to sometimes being < 1ms. Initially I thought it might be a difference in the amount of rows for a given partition when a specific account number is cached as a compiled value in the plan but that doesn't appear to be the case.
The plan that averages <1ms can be found here and the plan that seems to average ~7ms can be viewed here.
Note that this database is currently on SQL 2012 but we are in the process of upgrading to 2019 where I have been paying particular attention to the performance of this query.
We also only update stats once a week on this table with FULLSCAN, NORECOMPUTE so I know that stats shouldn't be changing frequently.
Any insights would be much appreciated.

It’s not just that you need an index on one of the columns, is it?  What’s the query?

No. There is already an index to support the query which results in an index seek. You should be able to view the query via either link for the plans.

The size of those execution plans basically breaks the paste the plan site for me due to the number of partitions and so values to RangePartitionNew - but when I did manage to get the XML the final execution plans are identical. Only difference is different compiled parameter values leading to different estimated rows and whether it entered full optimisation but the final plan is the same

when it takes 7ms maybe there is other activity happening on the server causing contention or it needs to read pages from disc.

Yeah some other activity was my first suspicion. Other than that it's hard ro see where there would be a difference as the partitions containing the parameterised values are very similar in size. Guess I'll have to look again at what else might be contributing to the change in behaviour.

I wouldn't even get out of bed for less than 10000ms in variance, so I don't think this sounds worrisome. I'm guessing parts of data get flushed out of buffer which might explain differences

The fact that the query duration changes does not indicate that there is any processing anomaly. A computer must process multiple requests simultaneously and puts them in a queue, hence stochastic phenomena that sometimes cause the duration to differ. Personally, when I perform benchmarks, the execution time calculation method I use requires launching the query 11 times. I eliminate the first duration because of caching, I also eliminate the smallest and largest duration and I average the other 8...

@SQLpro I would normally do the same, but in this case the change in duration (according to the monitoring tool) lasts for several hours at least so it isn't like I'm analysing a small sample size. The behaviour also occurs on most days at different times so it's difficult to even tie it to a specific process from the application. I'm also a little suspicious of the durations that are < 1ms seeing as this is a very large table with 8k+ individual partitions.

@bn25 is this table accessed for INSERTs, UPDATEs or DELETEs ? If yes a lock on a partition can delay the access sometime

The table is primarily INSERT with some DELETEs happening once a week for a short period of time. I haven't yet seen any lock related waits associated with this query and primarily see PAGEIOLATCH_SH. I have noticed that SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD waits are also shown when the duration is on the higher end.

Does your database setting has auto_update_statistics set to on? This might be doing you some unintended updates reading only 1% of the data:
select  name, is_auto_update_stats_on
from    sys.databases
what is the distribution of your 8k partitions? are they evenly distributed?
